# My website can't indexed by google

Tags: wordpress, indexing, web-crawler, google-search-console

**The whole history**

I think (I'm not sure about this) the site was hacked. Because of this, the website was with a lot of japanese stranger pages and not indexed by google.

**What's the problem?**

When I search for the site (http://adetecta.com.br/) google can't index the site in results.

If you search for Adetecta or Adetecta Campinas in the google, sometimes will apper the advertise for the site.

[The site is showing by advertising](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUCnL.png)

**What I've done to try to resolve the problem**

- A new indexing solicitation
- Add the url manually
- Add the new metatags
- Validate the site in the google webmaster tool
- Robots verification
- Try to force a new index by google (4 times)
- Try to contact my host to check for DNS problems (The host tells me: everything is ok with your DNS)

The stranger pages was removed but the google still showing the urls in the indexing process: site:adetecta.com.br

**Current status in the google webmaster tool**

> **Crawl Errors Site**
>
> DNS: not okay (Orange alert)
>   Server Connectivity Ok
>   robots.txt search Ok
>
> URL errors 4, Server Error 1, Access Denied 1, Soft 404 4 Not Found

I don't know what to do more, I'm completely lost, someone know what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created another site from zero and request a manually revision of the old domain in the google web master tools.

After some days, they send me a confirmation message:

> **Request for reconsideration approved** for http://www.xxxxxxxx.com.br/
>   To: webmaster of http://www.xxxxxxxxx.com.br/,
>   Good news! Your reconsideration request has been approved and Google has removed all manual actions on your site. Keep in mind that removing a manual action does not guarantee that your site's ranking will increase.